# Are there any predefined variables available in the template in angular dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

The dart documentation currently lacks a "few" details and google didn't help me either.

Are there any predefined variables or something like that in angulardart templates?
To clarify what I mean with that:

Something like {{baseURL}} or something like that. In short: stuff that angular provides to each template.

In Smarty (php templating) there is a debug directive that shows everything that is in the current scope, which is great for developing and debugging more complex templates. I assume that dart has nothing like that yet?

Comment: What information would you like to access? Anything specific?

Comment: Things like the current URL, the current route and so on. It might ease the creation of nice templates. And when for example some kind of debug component exists that displays what is currently in available, you could discover this yourself, but right now I have no clue how to find our if there are any predefined things.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve. In AngularDart it's quite easy to get most of the information. It has great DI system and you can pretty much inject anything into your components. I.e. have a look at https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html - RouteProvider for example. If you need some specific information, which you can't get, feel free to raise a github issue.

Comment: I just want to know if there are things that I can access in the template that are provided by angular, like {{currentUrl}} or maybe {{currentRoute}} or whatever. I know that I can use DI to wire things in my controllers. I'm only taling about the html templating. If angular does not define anything on it's own, that's ok, but if it does I don't have to do it again, that's why I am trying to find out what the templating engine may provide.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of...

Comment: But if you can think of something useful, and have a use case that would justify it, you should submit a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any suggestion that there are any. If there were, the list would need to be published, as it could easily clash with your own names, and would cause confusion.

If you need to access anything like this, I think it'd make more sense to add them to your object directly, it would make it much easier to understand (and debug) later!